# JSoup posting login data

Tags: html-parsing, jsoup

I am attempting to use JSoup for parsing HTML, logging into an account and then parsing additional HTML.

There are several tests I have performed on simple HTML, but I picked a website written in JSP that I have an account on, but I am not having any luck attempting to log into the site..

From the HTML, I have the following fields as part of the input:

```
input id="loginPopup" type="text" size="25" value="" name="/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.value.login" maxlength="46"

input type="hidden" value=" " name="_D:/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.value.login"
```

and

```
input id="passwordPopup" maxlength="25" name="/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.value.password" value="" type="password" autocomplete="off" size="25" 

input name="_D:/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.value.password" value=" " type="hidden"
```

After retrieving the HTML, I am executing the following:

```
        doc = Jsoup.connect(MAIN_URL)
              .data("/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.value.login", "xxxxxx@yahoo.com")
              .data("/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.value.password", "<password>");
              .post();
```

..actually, I have tried several combinations, but am having no success..  I end up getting the "wrong userid/password" screen...

I have also used JSoup to ensure I have the proper name value by:

```
        Element input = doc.getElementById("loginPopup");
        String inputName = input.attr("name");
```

I have been looking for other JSoup examples, and thought maybe someone here might have some insight...

I will be redirected to a secured (HTTPS) page, but I don't think that is the issue.  I am assuming it something to do with the strange "name" values of the HTML inputs..?

Thanks

Comment: That strange "name" value indicates that the website is running on Oracle ATG Commerce. I suggest you tag this question with "ATG".

Answer (score 0):

Use a chrome extension called POSTMAN to try simulate the login, Oracle ATG usually needs more fields to login than just Login and Password, open chrome Developer Tools and check the Network while doing a real  login to the site, then you will be able to see all the paramenters needed to simulate the login from code.

[]s